# Redux Issue - store.getState is not a function. (In 'store.getState()', 'store.getState' is undefined)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, persist

I've been trying to integrate redux-persist into a project that already uses redux.

I followed the basic usage example, but I get the error `store.getState is not a function.`

Here's the relevant code.

Store:

```
import {createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose} from "redux";
import {persistStore, autoRehydrate} from 'redux-persist'
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import marketData from "./reducers/marketDataReducer";
import coin from "./reducers/coinReducer";
import account from "./reducers/accountReducer";



const store = createStore(

  combineReducers({
       marketData,
       coin,
       account
    }),
    compose(
        applyMiddleware(thunk),
        autoRehydrate()
    ),


);
persistStore(store)
```

Entry:

```
import { Navigation } from 'react-native-navigation';
import { registerScreens } from './navigation';
import Welcome from "./containers/welcome";
import store from "./store";
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

    registerScreens(store, Provider);

    Navigation.startSingleScreenApp({
      screen: {
        screen: "welcome",
        navigatorStyle: { navBarHidden: true }
      }
    });
```

EDIT: Solution was very simple. Just make sure you export your store. Thanks to @markerikson

Comment: Are you actually exporting the store object from `store.js`?

Comment: I dont think, store is exported on the Store js file. once you export, you should have it running store.getState

Comment: Oh wow. Nice spot. Thank you

Comment: @markerikson You should write the solution in the answer for more visibility

Answer (score 4):

Doesn't look like you're actually exporting the `store` variable from your `store.js` file.  Fix that first, and see if it works.